# OnsenUI can't access component in code

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am working on an OnsenUI Cordova application, using `OnsenUI 1.3.1` (installed via bower), `AngularJS 1.3.15`, and `Cordova 5.0.0`. I'm having trouble getting to the `ons-navigator` object within JavaScript, and all of the methods mentioned in the OnsenUI website for doing so (http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#CallingComponentAPIsfromJavaScript) don't seem to work for me. I have my code set up as follows:

index.html:

```
...
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <ons-navigator id="navigator" var="myNavigator" page="{{targetPage}}">
        <div>
            Hello!
        </div>
      </ons-navigator>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
...
```

MainController:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('MainController', ['$log', '$scope',
    function ($log, $scope) {
      $scope.initialize = function () {
        $scope.targetPage = 'views/login.html';

        $log.info('scope navigator: ' + $scope.myNavigator);    // comes back as undefined
        $log.info('find navigator: ' + ons.findComponent('ons-navigator#navigator', document.body));    // comes back as null
      };

      $scope.initialize();

    }]);
```

I'm currently not outputting the methods outlined in the OnsenUI documentation that utilize the `ons.findParentComponentUntil()` method or the one that involves changing the component based object, but I have looked into those, and they don't seem to work either (comes back undefined).

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the navigator element before it has been created, try to execute your code with `ons.ready();`, for example:

```js
 ons.ready(function() {
      
      console.log("scope navigator: " + $scope.myNavigator);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did end up figuring out that timing was bad on this one. So instead, I find that I can access the navigator on the `.run()` method after bootstrapping Onsen/Angular. So I suppose, is that approach better or worse than using the `ons.ready()`? Thanks!

Comment: @Norbii `ons.ready()` is the best option. The function is called when Onsen UI initialization is done. If the app is running under Cordova or PhoneGap, it will also wait for its initialization (`ondeviceready` event).
If the answer satisfies you, please consider to upvote and mark it as the best answer. It will give the opportunity, to users that have the same problem, to find the answer easily. ;)

Comment: It is indeed! Thank you very much! I can't upvote yet, but I have marked it as the answer.